# Retrive all Global variables declared (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, variables, global

I'm trying to list all global variables declared in my code in a "passive" way, i mean, not manually creating a List(of T) and then add one by one into the list.
I have this custom Object, lets say Car.vb, i declared a lot of them as global and them populated all the "Cars" one by one in the load event. But some where in my code i want to perform a loop in all the "Cars", ok I could manage a List(of T) but if tomorrow i add 4 more cars in the Global scope, i must to add manually this 4 cars into the List(of T) too, other wise this new 4 cars will not be part of the loop. So i started to think if there's some way to list all variable of a specific type declared in code.
Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: There's Reflection. Before you ask, no I won't explain further. You can search for that term and read up on it, then ask specific questions later if you encounter specific issues.

Comment: How are you variables "global"?  This sounds like a potential design issue that you're trying to work around instead of trying to fix.

Comment: Maybe a method to create cars would be the ideal option. That method would automatically add the new cars to the list.

Comment: Something like what @the_lotus suggests, is a simpler, more obvious and self-documenting approach, but beware.  If you actually maintain a list of references to those objects, those objects will never be deleted from memory by the garbage collector, thereby causing a memory leak.  You could use a list of `WeakReference` objects to reference them, but that adds a little more complication, in which case reflection may be preferable.  However, as @David pointed out, this has a very bad code smell, so your first instinct should be to rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks everyone.... @jmcilhinney Reflection is something new to me. But I got how to list all the variables using it, thanks for the hint. Now i'm facing trouble to convert back to the original Class.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got how to do this:

```
        Dim Cars_List As New List(Of Car)

        Dim assbly As Assembly = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim types As Type() = assbly.GetTypes()

        For Each t As Type In types
            If t.Name = "Form1" Then
                For Each p As FieldInfo In t.GetFields()
                    If p.FieldType.Name = "Car" Then
                        Console.WriteLine(p.Name & "  - " & p.FieldType.Name)
                        Cars_List.Add(CallByName(Me, p.Name, vbGet))
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Declare Car as Public instead of using Dim, in order for this to works.